# Measurability of functions

Tags: measure-theory

I have to check that $g:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

I known there exists a $C^2$ convex function $F:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ (with $F''\geq 1$), and measurable functions $v,u:(0,1)\to (0,1)$ such that $v>u$ and
$$F(v(x))-F(u(x))=(v(x)-u(x))F'(g(x)) $$
for any $x$.

My argument is the following:
since $F''\geq 1$, $F'$ is increasing, thus $(F')^{-1}:Image(F')\to (0,1)$ is well defined , and from
$$F(v(x))-F(u(x))=(v(x)-u(x))F'(g(x)) $$
I get
$$(F')^{-1}\left(\frac{F(v(x))-F(u(x))}{v(x)-u(x)}\right)=g(x), $$
hence $g$ is measurable. However I am a bit unsure about this. Any advise is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to be careful what you mean by measurable. Do you mean Borel or Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perfectly right. $F$ and $F'$ and $(F')^{-1}$ are measurable because they are continuous, this because $F$ is $C^1$. (The fact that $F$ is $C^2$, in fact only $C^1$ with $F'$ differentiable is sufficient, is only used to through the fact that $F''$ exists and is $\geq 1$, which ensures that $F^{-1}$ exists.) And as $u$ and $v$ are measurable, you get by composition and algebraic operations that $x\mapsto (F')^{-1}\left(\frac{F(v(x))-F(u(x))}{v(x)-u(x)}\right)=g(x)$ is measurable.

Comment: Is $(F')^{-1}$ necessarily Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable? If being measurable above means Lebesgue measurable, then we need $(F')^{-1}$ to be Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Mesurable means Lebesgue measurable, yes. As I wrote, $F$ and $F'$ and $(F')^{-1}$ are measurable because they are continuous. Now generally, if $f$ is differentiable, it is a fortiori continuous, and $f'(x) = \lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)}{x+\frac{1}{n}-x} = \lim_{n\to+\infty} f_n (x)$, and the $f_n$ are continuous, so that they are measurable, and $f_n$ converges simply to $f'$, so that $f'$ is simple limit of measurable functions, and is measurable also, even if it is not continuous necess cont.But in our case $(F')^{-1}$ is measurable because it it continuous.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Milly You're welcome !

Comment: I don't get this. The inside function is presumably Lebesgue-Borel measurable, that is, the inverse image of a Borel set is a Lebesgue set. Unless $(F')^{-1}$ is a Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable function, then one cannot conclude that the composition is measurable. That was the point of my initial remark.

Comment: @copper.hat To be precise : it suffices that $(F')^{-1}$ is measurable to ensure that $g$ is measurable, yes. And $(F')^{-1}$ is measurable by the 1st paragraph of my answer.

Comment: A continuous function is automatically Lebesgue-Borel measurable but not necessarily Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable.